# Rearrange Stacked Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I currently have the below dataframe and am looking to rearrange it to eventually plot the bounds. The dataframe is composed of results of a bootstrap from n = 10^4.01 to 10^4.5, however, my results seem to be stacked on top of each other.

```
        ci.bound X1 X2 X3  X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
     1         1  0  0 10 -10  0  0  0  0  0   0
     2         2  0  0 10 -10  0  0  0  0  0   0
     3  ci.bound X1 X2 X3  X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
     4         1  0  0 10 -10  0  0  0  0  0   0
     5         2  0  0 10 -10  0  0  0  0  0   0
     6  ci.bound X1 X2 X3  X4                   
     7         1  0  0 10 -10                   
     8         2  0  0 10 -10
```

I've tried using the reshape function but I'm not exactly sure how to get the result I'm looking for, ideally, I'd like to create something similar to the below dataframe:

```
         ci.bound ci.1 ci.2 ci.3  ci.4 
     X1         1    0    0    0     0
     X1         2    0    0    0     0
     X2         1    0    0    0     0
     X2         2    0    0    0     0                
     X3         1   10   10   10    10    
     X3         2   10   10   10    10
     X4         1  -10  -10  -10   -10
     X4         2  -10  -10  -10   -10
     X5         1    0    0    0     0
     X5         2    0    0    0     0
     X6         1    0    0    0     0
     X6         2    0    0    0     0
     X7         1    0    0    0     0
     X7         2    0    0    0     0
     X8         1    0    0    0     0
     X8         2    0    0    0     0
     X9         1    0    0    0     0
     X9         2    0    0    0     0
    X10         1    0    0    0     0
    X10         2    0    0    0     0
```

```
    > dput(xdot.fourzeroone.fourfive)
    structure(list(ci.bound = c("1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", 
    "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2", "ci.bound", "1", "2"), X1 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "X1"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "X2"), class = "factor"), X3 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("10", "X3"), class = "factor"), X4 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("-10", "X4"), class = "factor"), 
        X5 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "0", "X5"), class = "factor"), 
        X6 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "0", "X6"), class = "factor"), 
        X7 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "0", "X7"), class = "factor"), 
        X8 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "0", "X8"), class = "factor"), 
        X9 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "0", "X9"), class = "factor"), 
        X10 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "0", "X10"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -149L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is that what you mean by dput?

Comment: have a doubt.  in your input, there are up to 'X10', so would the expected have up to 10 columns

Comment: For a significant amount of the results there are 10 columns. If it is possible, I can fill the ones without 10 columns with zero or NA. I just need have the ability to graph all of the confidence intervals.